# Why is this search form input using Twitter Bootstrap rendering oddly?

Tags: safari, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap as my HTML/CSS framework for a Rails site.

Here's my simple search form:

```
<form class="form-search" id="new_search" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
  <input class="search-query" size="30" type="text">
  <button class="btn" name="button" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

The rendered input box has strange artifacts on the right side (see image below) when rendered in Safari. The problem is not there in Chrome.

[image: Search Input Rendering Bug]

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Others have complained about similar rendering issues in Safari 6.0 on Mountain Lion (see [Bootstrap Issue #4217](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4217)).  Since it was seen across different sites, it is being labeled a Safari issue, and it is suggested to try filing a bug report with Apple.